# how to save data from json to code igniter?

Tags: json, codeigniter

i have two records

```
num | choice | name
--------------------
1   | A      | Jen
2   | C      | Jhon
---------------------
```

and i have result json like below

```
"{"1":"A, Jen","2":"C, Jhon"}"
```

How to create Save data in Codeigniter from it json?

Thank You

Comment: to convert the data to the json use json_encode($name_of_array_string); and to convert back to array use json_decode($name_of_json_string);  use print_r(); to see the output

Comment: Array
(
    [1] => A, Jen
    [2] => C, Jhon
) how to get Jen and Jhon ?

Comment: Do you mean you want to strip away "A, " from "A, Jen" ?

Comment: Do you mean you want to know how to insert that exact json into the database where the result is the same as your records?

Comment: @sonyweb use explode http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php delimit with "," and pick $array[1]

Comment: if using delimiter ',' how about if example Jen replace with "Jen, Jinny"..? @Magic-Mouse

Comment: that's another question

Comment: Maybe you are looking for http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php or use explode() as suggested by @Magic-Mouse - or from your comment, maybe you look to first get the array then use `implode()` to put it back together with ',' ? http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php

Answer (score 3):

Use `json_decode()` to make it into an array for saving.

For example, to save the json in your database, use:

```
$data_array = json_decode($json_data, true); // the "true" parameter makes it an associative array instead of object
// possible data modeling here...
$this->db->insert('table_name', $data_array);
```

Of course you might want to loop the array for db insert like:

```
$data_array = json_decode($json_data, true);
foreach ($data_array as $data_row):
   // possible data modeling here...
   $this->db->insert('table_name', $data_row);
endforeach;
```

See reference here http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Answer (score 0):

Since Mysql 5.7 there is native JSON storage support, if you don't have MySQL 5.7 you could always use a longtext field and then you can do json_decode($result) when you want to have it converted back to an array / object.

At the very first, if this is exactly what your JSON is, than ur doing something wrong, that is an invalid JSON string.

Make sure to use some validator for your json, here is some example json:

```
$myJson = '{
    "employees": [{
        "firstName": "John",
        "lastName": "Doe"
    }, {
        "firstName": "Anna",
        "lastName": "Smith"
    }, {
        "firstName": "Peter",
        "lastName": "Jones"
    }]
}';
```

Example:

```
$this->db->insert($this->table, ['json_field' => $myJson]);
```

To read it you can do:

```
$result = $this->db->select('json_field')->from($this->table)->result_row();
$backToArray = (array) json_decode($result);
```

Been awhile since I did CodeIgniter so i'm not entirely sure wether it's completely correct but it should give you a general idea of how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

you can save json in table or you can use json_decode() to save separate column.

in your controller

```
public function insert_json(){
 $data = json_decode($json_result, true);
 foreach ($data as $row){
 $this->Your_model->save_json($row);
 }
}
```

and model

```
public function save_json($data){
$this->db->insert('table_name', $data);
}
```